# System.out.print() doesn't send any output to Eclipse console. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I have the following Java class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1448; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this code in Eclipse IDE, I don't see any output in Eclipse console.

If I change value **1448** and set for example **1447** or less, I see output in console (12345678...)

So, maybe Eclipse IDE has restrictions on string length in console?

What do you think about this?

Comment: I can confirm this. Eclipse for Java EE Indigo. For 1448 or higher there is "no" output, i.e. seem there are whitespaces which I can mark with my mouse. But it seems to work with `System.out.println`

Comment: Outputs fine in my eclipse (Indigo Service Release 2 on OSX 10.7.4), even for larger values (10000)

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=87299

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Right click on in console -> `Preferences...` -> check `Fixed width console`. Now you have auto word wrap and everything shows ok. Seems like Eclipse console have a limit on number of characters displayed in one line.

Comment: Indeed, this works. Eng.Fouad linked to the relevant bug in the OP's comments.

Answer (score 10):

According to [this](http://geekbridage.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/increase-console-buffer-in-eclipse/), Eclipse does indeed restrict the size of its output buffer.

Of course, you can change this behaviour:

> Go to *Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console* and un-check *Limit
>   console output*; or you can
>   provide any number of characters between 1000 to 1000000.

Edit: It does not seem to fix your problem though.

Comment: No wonder it always used to work for me. I have unchecked the option "Limit console output"

Comment: this is related to number of lines, not output width.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code in my copy of Eclipse Helio IDE. It works for smaller number as per your said. But in case of larger number  it is actually printing in the consol but the ouput is not displaying. You can see it, if you try to copy and paste it in the coding editor or some other editor like notepad.

If you use **println()** it will show the output. Instead you can also use **print(i+ "\t")** to see the output.

Comment: You have a great tongue! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `\t` solved my problem.

Example: `System.out.println("Result:\t" + data);`

Comment: Did using println vs print have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

How to System.out.println out to console:
Right click on your glassfish (Server tab) and go to View Log File

[image]

Make sure the console setting is directed at your server.log file:
 [image]