# Java Anomaly in Simple Context

Tags: java

I'm encountering a very strange anomaly in the run() method of a thread.

```
public class project extends JApplet implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener, Runnable {
  private boolean gameStarted;
  public void init() {
    gameStarted = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
  }
  public void run() {
     while (true) {
        if (gameStarted)
           System.out.print("OK");
     }  
  }
}
```

The variable gameStarted is true, but the system does not print anything as a result. This is part of a larger class which is the base class for a game I'm working on. However, this has me completely stumped and I can't understand why this won't work. If instead of gameStarted I put `true` in the if statement, it does print out OK.

Also note, if I change the run() method to the following, it works exactly as expected given that gameStarted is true:

```
public void run() {
     while (true) {
        System.out.print(gameStarted);
        if (gameStarted)
           System.out.print("OK");
     }  
  }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Post compilable code please

Comment: Mark gameStarted as `volatile`?

Comment: This is a "spin" loop - 100% CPU. If you have other similarly coded Runnables running, it's possible your code's thread never gets scheduled.

Comment: The only threads running are the main thread and the one created in this class

Comment: It seems it is running but console just can't show print result. When I switch to System.out.println("OK"); It works. It's quite strange.

Comment: Making gameStarted volatile seems to have fixed the issue, although I can't say I quite understand why the issue was occurring. Especially since I had been successfully using what I believe was the exact same code before without making the variable volatile.

Comment: @Drogba The print statement is there for simplicity's sake, however I had already tried using println and it didn't work. Regardless, it still was not working for the actual code I need to put in the if statement, until I made gameStarted volatile.

Comment: It's a eclipse console problem.
Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948983/system-out-print-doesnt-send-any-output-to-eclipse-console-why

Comment: i guess, system console don't have opportunity to print the results. because of the loop within run method.  try a Thread.sleep within your loop to let other threads do their job.

Comment: @Drogba I'm not using Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that there your thread is not seeing the update made by the main thread on the variable "gameStarted" (race condition). If you make the variable gameStarted as "volatile" does it make a difference? I think making it volatile makes sure that your thread will see the latest value which in this case is "true" set by main thread.

Comment: Setting gameStarted to volatile does work. However if you look at my 2nd example, it works exactly as expected by adding another println before the if statement. If what you're saying is correct, then having a println statement before the if allows for gameStarted to be rendered as true when it arrives at the if statement...

Comment: Yes, I believe so. But I would not rely on the extra println before the if statement to fix the timing issue and rather make the variable a volatile.