# Something wrong about Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse Kepler doesn't work when I create a java project. Even an easy example done't have output, either.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

But when I ran it, nothing appeared on the console.

Just like this
[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Did you re-compile the class before running it?

Comment: Similar post is available, you could try this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948983/system-out-print-doesnt-send-any-output-to-eclipse-console-why

Comment: The methods they offered were no used for my problem...Maybe the IDE crashed...

Comment: Show screenshots of the entire editor view and the entire package explorer view, showing this source file in the listing.